# Creating a popup when a button is pressed[JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So I'm working on a chrome extension, and I want to open a popup that contains an entry field whenever a button is clicked.

Is there any way to do this? I've been trying to do this for a couple hours now, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate as programming way, share some code so some one can help you.

Comment: you want to work with chrome extension? or you just want to show a simple prompt box to get a value using jquery?

Comment: @Bharat I'm not really sure how showing my code will help. All I need to know is how to create a popup with an entry field. Besides, I'd rather not have other people write my code for me.

Comment: @Ali I want to show a simple prompt box to get a value in a chrome extension.

Comment: I can't understand why are you stressing on "in chrome extension". i believe as long as you are not the author of any chrome extension you can't make modifications in it.

Comment: @Ali oh, it is my chrome extension. I can't figure out how to make a popup, however.

Comment: What do you mean by "popup" ? Have you tried `prompt("Enter a value:", "")` ?

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I couldn't find that solution. When I searched it up, I got solutions like [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html), or [this](http://istockphp.com/jquery/creating-popup-div-with-jquery/). All of those solutions seemed too complicated, so I wanted to know if there was a simple way. Thanks a lot. EDIT: Hm, is there any way to add anything to a prompt box? A prompt box is what I'm looking for, but I'd like to have another button on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to diplay a popup dialog with a single entry field is **[`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt)**.
E.g.:

```
var value = prompt('Please, enter a value below:',
                   '<the field is pre0filled with this text>');
if (value === null) { /* Cancelled or closed */ }
else { /* value set (could be an empty string) */ }
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to further customize the dialog's appearance (e.g. location, size, style, button-labels etc).

---

If it is OK to use jQuery-UI, you can use the **[*Dialog* widget](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)**.